# Handling opposites when adding and subtracting rational expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

I'm following example 8.47 from the OpenStax book [Elementary Algebra](https://openstax.org/details/books/elementary-algebra).

When trying to create a common denominator it is sometimes necessary to handle opposites on either side of an equation.

In the example, $(2-n)$ needs to be converted to $(n-2)$ as follows:

$$-\frac{(n+3)}{(2-n)}$$

To do this we multiply the numerator and denominator by $-1$.

$$-\frac{(-1)(n+3)}{(-1)(2-n)}$$

Which gives:

$$+\frac{(n+3)}{(n-2)}$$

I understand why the denominator changes but not why the numerator stays the same and the sign of the whole expression changes. Could someone explain this, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't forget the minus sign 'outside' the fraction disappeared as well:

$$-\frac{(-1)(n+3)}{(-1)(2-n)}=$$
$$-1\frac{(-1)(n+3)}{(-1)(2-n)}=$$
$$\frac{-1\cdot-1\cdot(n+3)}{(-1)(2-n)}=$$
$$\frac{(n+3)}{(-1)(2-n)}=$$
$$\frac{(n+3)}{(n-2)}$$

Comment: Sorry to be stupid but why has the **-1** moved from the numerator to the 'whole' expression?

Comment: That's how fractions work; everything 'in front of' the fraction is actually part of the numerator.